# For my App - Can't play video on Android lollipop 5.1.1 but playing on emulator

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

```
 VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);
 String UrlPath="android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.ff;
 videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
 Uri video = Uri.parse(UrlPath);
 videoView.setVideoURI(video);
 setContentView(videoView);
 videoView.start();
```

Video is playing in Android emulator running on Lollipop but not playing on device running on Lollipop. Error is Video can't play.

Comment: The problem is usually the other way round - the emulator is not able to play some videos as it or the underlying PC do not have enough power. What type of video is this, and what type of Android device?

Comment: Video is MP4, its playing in Emulator and not playing in my mobile phone running on Lollipop 5.1.1. But playing on other phones. Problem might be only with my mobile. Normal videos in gallery are played without any problem.